# Oracle Impdp Import to exclude empty tables

Tags: sql, oracle, import, oracle11g

On occasion I need to import and Oracle .DMP file into a new Oracle Database.  There are usually may tables in the import that are empty, i.e. they have no rows of data in them.  My question is two-fold:

1.  Is there a way, during the import (impdp) process to exclude any tables with zero rows?

2.  Would doing so jeopardize the integrity of the import in any way?

  Keep in mind that I only care about getting what data there is into Oracle, becasue then I turn around and import it into a Sql Server Db, so having a "working" Oracle Db is not the end goal here, it's getting the existing data from Oracle into Sql.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any way to skip a table, other than by excluding it from a list of tables to import; but that would be by name, which I think you're trying to avoid.

If the tables already exist in the target database then importing zero rows isn't going to add any (appreciable) overhead. If they don't exist then you'd risk problems with referential integrity constraints (i.e. foreign keys); I don't think the `DATA_OPTIONS` parameter would avoid that, but it isn't one I've used. Although if a child table has zero rows, that rather implies the parent would also have zero rows, so both would be excluded. If it were possible...